# JQuery Datepicker hiding behind flash object

Tags: flash, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker which loads up above a flash movie space, and right now the datepicker loads behind it and hidden, I tried setting the z-index value of date picker to a high number and z index of the object tag to a lower value, but doesnt work, I also tried setting the wmode param in the object tag to 'transparent' but doesnt work in IE.

This issue is only with I.E. v8 and not with firefox or chrome.

Thanks
Priyank

Comment: This article can help I think
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326196/ff3-windows-css-z-index-problem-with-youtube-player