# youtube embed over stickytop nav - IE7

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-7, youtube, z-index

How could I get my top sticky nav to remain on top of my youtube embed on IE 7?! I have a long vertical scrolling site, which I've conditioned to work in IE7 - BUT, there is a youtube video in one scroll section, and when you scroll passed it, it goes over the top sticky menu?

Do I need to wrap a div around it, and assign a 9999 z-index to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every site I've ever been on, the Youtube play always stays on top of the other elements. Assigning 9999 z-index won't solve the problem.

The only solution would be to make the Youtube Flash Player stay behind other elements - check the Youtube help on that to see if you can change any settings.

Comment: It stays behind the top sticky menu / fixed menu on all other browsers? Just not IE 7..

Comment: No. Not sure if Google wants you doing this, but there is a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326196/ff3-windows-css-z-index-problem-with-youtube-player).